# Good example of use of JSF and Spring Architecture

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am trying to find a good example of use of JSF and Spring with installation instruction,But haven't been able to find something more than basic.

Can anyone direct me to nice examples?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [java Beat : integrating-spring-and-jsf](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/39-integrating-spring-and-jsf-1.html)
- [jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out Appfuse, http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home, it has the whole enchilada: maven, security (acegi), webservices, hibernate search (lucene), caching (ehcache), JPA, annotations in JSF Managed Beans, transactions, templating (sitemesh), email, and lots of other useful stuff. I find it a bit too complex, not so sure if it uses the best available components for JSF, but it's an application skeleton for the real world.
See the reference at http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Reference+Guide