# Manage beans via Spring or via JSF

Tags: spring, jsf

In my JSF Webapp I am using Spring vor DI etc.

At the moment I have my beans managed by Spring.
(`SpringBeanFacesELResolver` defined in `faces-config.xml`)

But I'm not sure, if this is the right way...
For example: A bean defined in Spring cannot use the new JSF 2 view scope, right?

My question is not, if I should use Spring or not... Just HOW to manage my beans?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good example of use of JSF and Spring Architecture.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547869/good-example-of-use-of-jsf-and-spring-architecture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should in any case stick with one DI in your project. For me, Spring is clearly much more powerful that JSF managed beans. So I would opt to Spring in this situation.

You can hanlde view scope in Spring using custom scopes, it is quite straigtforward actually. Here's a [blog post](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) on this question.